# Как обратиться к связанной таблицы один ко одному?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Немного не пойму как получить данные из связанной таблицы, вроде бы все по документации делаю, но возникают проблемы
В таблица
**shedule**

```
id | date | start | end | direction_id | user_id | created_at | updated_at
```

**direction**

```
id | name | created_at | updated_at
```

И мне нужно чтобы я обратился к shedule и получить данные из таблицы direction
Я организовал связь

```
class Shedule extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'shedule';
    protected $fillable = ['date', 'start', 'end', 'direction_id', 'type', 'user_id', 'branch_id', 'room_id'];

    public function directions()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Growth\Direction');
    }
}


class Direction extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'direction';
    protected $fillable = ['id_user', 'name'];

    public function shedule()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Growth\Shedule');
    }
}
```

И когда обращаюсь к моделе не получается пишет null

```
$shedules = Shedule::with('directions')->where('user_id', $user)->where('date', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))->get();
        foreach ($shedules as $shedule){
            dd($shedule->directions);
        }
```

Но не пойму почему выскакивает null, Вроде бы как должна модель directon выскакивать

Answer (score 0):

```
public function directions()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Growth\Direction', 'direction_id', 'id');
}
```